# Adding the current node title as the value of the comment form title?

Tags: 7, forms, hooks, comments

**I want a value to be automatically added to the title text-field in the comment form ; this value would be indeed the current node title.**

I've started working on a `hook_form_alter()` (added in a custom module already installed and enabled) like this one :

```
   function ta_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   if ($form_id == 'comment-form') {
        $form['comment']['title']['#value'] = 'Blablabla';
    }
   }
```

But as you might guess it's not working... I've got several issues:

- Is the `$form_id` the right one ?
- I didn't manage to successfully use `print_r($form)` (or it returned nothing) so I
  guessed the path to the title value. Might be incorrect too...
- And finally, I really don't know how to get the current node title
  variable, so as to attribute it the title value!

Thanks for reading, I hope I've been understandable !  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, you most likely have the `$form_id` wrong.  To check this you can use `drupal_set_message($form_id);` and refresh the page to see all form ids on the current page.

Once you have the form id correct, *then* you can use `print_r($form);`

For example, I got this working on the comment form on my node type "Announcement":

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'comment_node_announcement_form') {
    $form['subject']['#default_value'] = $form['#node']->title;
    //print_r($form);
  }
  //drupal_set_message($form_id); // Use to get $form_id
}
```

Comment: Thks for the drupal_set_message($form_id) trick, very useful ! The rest of the code you gave works perfectly. The only crappy thing is that I'll have to add an "OR comment_node_TYPE_form" in the IF condition for each content-type I want to make it... But, that works at least ! ^^